# MySQL distinct desde tipo de campo DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime

tengo una lista con datos seleccionados a partir de fecha, el campo de fecha es de tipo DATETIME.

```
FECHA 15-08-2017 14:41:12;
ID 150;
DATO 80
```

de un total de 1000 registros se requiere saber cuántas veces cambió el valor del campo DATO y qué valores tuvo en una determinada fecha y hora.

Yo estaba pensando separar el campo FECHA que es de tipo DATETIME y extraer solamente la fecha y hora para obtener los resultados solo de los datos que cambiaron. Para eso estaba pensando usar DATE_FORMAT, pero no consigo hacer funcionar mi consulta.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código que has probado hasta la fecha?

Comment: Si quieres saber cuántas veces cambió el valor de campo `dato` es una consulta (agrupando por el tipo de dato, supongo). Si quieres saber qué valor tenía dada una fecha y hora, entonces no veo para qué querrías explotar el campo de tipo DATETIME, que ya te dice qué valor tenía en esa fecha y hora. A lo mejor a lo que te refieres es a calcular cuántas veces cambió el valor en un mismo día?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, lo que indicas es correcto, lo que deseo saber es cuantas veces cambio el valor  en un determinado tiempo y cuales fueron esos valores con fecha y hora, para ello quería usar la siguiente consulta: SELECT dt.ID, dt.DATO 
from (SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, "%d %m %Y"), date(FECHA) 
FROM pruebas1.dt) as FECHA; Agradezco su gentil atención saludos.